# How do I use environmental variables in a systemd conf file that's defined in the same file?

Tags: systemd

Contents of `/etc/my-service/my-service.conf`:

```
MSG="Hello world!"
MSG2=$MSG
```

Contents of `/etc/systemd/system/my-service.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyService
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
EnvironmentFile=/etc/my-service/my-service.conf
WorkingDirectory=/home/my-username/my-project
ExecStart=/home/my-username/my-project/bash-script
Restart=on-failure
Nonbkocking=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Contents of `bash-script`:
e

```
echo hi > hi.txt
echo $MSG > msg.txt
echo $MSG2 > msg2.txt
```

I ran these commands

```
sudo systemctl enable my-service.service
sudo systemctl start my-service.service
```

I got the following files in `/home/my-username/my-project`...

Contents of `hi.txt`: `hi`

Contents of `msg.txt`: `Hello world!`

Contents of `msg2.txt`: `$MSG`

I thought `$MSG` would equal `Hello world!`.

How do I set `$MSG` to be equal to `$MSG`?